# Show that the sequence is convergent with the following result.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this exercise but I do not understand how to start, I appreciate if someone can help me (I attach the image).

*Every monotonic and bounded sequence is convergent*. Use this result to show that the following sequence is convergent.

$\{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}\times (n!)^2}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z^+}$[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0t18.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Observe that $\frac {u_{n+1}} { u_n} \lt 1$ and $\{u_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is clearly bounded below by $0.$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just an explanation of @Fanatics:

Let, $u_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}\times (n!)^2}$

So, $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{n+1}$ [Reduced form, after the  cancellation the terms from numerator and denominator].

So, we observed that $u_{n+1}<u_n$ because $\frac{1}{2}<1\implies n+\frac{1}{2}<n+1\implies \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}<1 $. i.e. $\{u_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence and bounded below by $0$. So, convergent.